# Memory issue while handle & process multiple large bitmaps

Tags: android, image, bitmap, out-of-memory, heap-memory

I have to let user capture 10 images from device camera one by one, then process each of them with gray scaling and then at the end upload them on server.

Now in low end android devices with less than 1 gb RAM i am facing a problem where due to memory / heap issue, page is getting reloaded once again while navigating back to app from camera app, all edittext data remains set but set thumbnails in imageviews disappears.

Steps:

1. Capture mutiple as much as 10 images
2. GrayScale each
3. Check for orientation and save with proper orientation
4. Show small thumnail of grayscaled image
5. 2nd, 3rd and 4th steps are done in AsyncTask
6. On Submit upload all 10 images (large saved bitmaps from SD Card) with other data to server

I have referred following tutorials on android developer:

## For image compression and scaling:

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

## For image grayscaling :

```
bmpGrayscale = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height,
                    Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas c = new Canvas(bmpGrayscale);
Paint paint = new Paint();
ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix();
cm.setSaturation(0);
ColorMatrixColorFilter f = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm);
paint.setColorFilter(f);
c.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, paint);
```

## For orientation handling :

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(picPath);
    ExifInterface exif = null;
    try {
        exif = new ExifInterface(uri.getPath());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    int rotation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                        ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

    rotationInDegrees = exifToDegrees(rotation);

    private static int exifToDegrees(int exifOrientation) {
        if (exifOrientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90) {
            return 90;
        } else if (exifOrientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180) {
            return 180;
        } else if (exifOrientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270) {
            return 270;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public static Bitmap rotate(Bitmap b, int degrees) {
        if (degrees != 0 && b != null) {
            Matrix m = new Matrix();

            m.setRotate(degrees, (float) b.getWidth() / 2,
                    (float) b.getHeight() / 2);
            // m.postRotate(degrees);
            try {
                System.gc();
                Bitmap b2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(b, 0, 0, b.getWidth(),
                        b.getHeight(), m, true);
                if (b != b2) {
                    b.recycle();
                    b = b2;
                }
            } catch (OutOfMemoryError ex) {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
        return b;
    }
```

Can anyone please guide how can i compress or handle memory such a way that i do all above steps and the said memory / heap issue does not occur.

Can caching of image help, i tried but it is not helping the way i implemented it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are doing bimap.recycle - good. I found that I had to save each camera image to disk and then process each sequentially from service or sync task. Bitmaps are very memory intensive and depending on how much memory is on the phone can only handle a couple at a time. When saving to disk, adjust the jpg compression so when read back in less memory is consumed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code, Not sure how exactly it works but it does work to save you memory on bitmap once you take it from camera or gallery. I can whole lot of pics with this one. Create a class with this in there and then call it in your activity

import java.io.File;

import java.io.FileInputStream;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.Config;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;

public class DecodeImage
{

//decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
public static Bitmap decodeFile(File bitmapFile, int requiredWidth, int requiredHeight, boolean quickAndDirty)
{
    try
    {
        //Decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options bitmapSizeOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bitmapSizeOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(bitmapFile), null, bitmapSizeOptions);

        // load image using inSampleSize adapted to required image size
        BitmapFactory.Options bitmapDecodeOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bitmapDecodeOptions.inTempStorage = new byte[16 * 1024];
        bitmapDecodeOptions.inSampleSize = computeInSampleSize(bitmapSizeOptions, requiredWidth, requiredHeight, false);
        bitmapDecodeOptions.inPurgeable = true;
        bitmapDecodeOptions.inDither = !quickAndDirty;
        bitmapDecodeOptions.inPreferredConfig = quickAndDirty ? Bitmap.Config.RGB_565 : Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;

        Bitmap decodedBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(bitmapFile), null, bitmapDecodeOptions);

        // scale bitmap to mathc required size (and keep aspect ratio)

        float srcWidth = (float) bitmapDecodeOptions.outWidth;
        float srcHeight = (float) bitmapDecodeOptions.outHeight;

        float dstWidth = (float) requiredWidth;
        float dstHeight = (float) requiredHeight;

        float srcAspectRatio = srcWidth / srcHeight;
        float dstAspectRatio = dstWidth / dstHeight;

        // recycleDecodedBitmap is used to know if we must recycle intermediary 'decodedBitmap'
        // (DO NOT recycle it right away: wait for end of bitmap manipulation process to avoid
        // java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap android.graphics.Bitmap@416ee7d8
        // I do not excatly understand why, but this way it's OK

        boolean recycleDecodedBitmap = false;

        Bitmap scaledBitmap = decodedBitmap;
        if (srcAspectRatio < dstAspectRatio)
        {
            scaledBitmap = getScaledBitmap(decodedBitmap, (int) dstWidth, (int) (srcHeight * (dstWidth / srcWidth)));
            // will recycle recycleDecodedBitmap
            recycleDecodedBitmap = true;
        }
        else if (srcAspectRatio > dstAspectRatio)
        {
            scaledBitmap = getScaledBitmap(decodedBitmap, (int) (srcWidth * (dstHeight / srcHeight)), (int) dstHeight);
            recycleDecodedBitmap = true;
        }

        // crop image to match required image size

        int scaledBitmapWidth = scaledBitmap.getWidth();
        int scaledBitmapHeight = scaledBitmap.getHeight();

        Bitmap croppedBitmap = scaledBitmap;

      /**      if (scaledBitmapWidth > requiredWidth)
        {
            int xOffset = (scaledBitmapWidth - requiredWidth) / 2;
            croppedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap, xOffset, 0, requiredWidth, requiredHeight);
            scaledBitmap.recycle();
        }
        else if (scaledBitmapHeight > requiredHeight)
        {
            int yOffset = (scaledBitmapHeight - requiredHeight) / 2;
            croppedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap, 0, yOffset, requiredWidth, requiredHeight);
            scaledBitmap.recycle();
        }
**/
            if (recycleDecodedBitmap)
        {
            decodedBitmap.recycle();
        }
        decodedBitmap = null;

        scaledBitmap = null;
        return croppedBitmap;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

/**
 * compute powerOf2 or exact scale to be used as {@link BitmapFactory.Options#inSampleSize} value (for subSampling)
 * 
 * @param requiredWidth
 * @param requiredHeight
 * @param powerOf2
 *            weither we want a power of 2 sclae or not
 * @return
 */
public static int computeInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int dstWidth, int dstHeight, boolean powerOf2)
{
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    // Raw height and width of image
    final int srcHeight = options.outHeight;
    final int srcWidth = options.outWidth;

    if (powerOf2)
    {
        //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.

        int tmpWidth = srcWidth, tmpHeight = srcHeight;
        while (true)
        {
            if (tmpWidth / 2 < dstWidth || tmpHeight / 2 < dstHeight)
                break;
            tmpWidth /= 2;
            tmpHeight /= 2;
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Calculate ratios of height and width to requested height and width
        final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) srcHeight / (float) dstHeight);
        final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) srcWidth / (float) dstWidth);

        // Choose the smallest ratio as inSampleSize value, this will guarantee
        // a final image with both dimensions larger than or equal to the
        // requested height and width.
        inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}

public static Bitmap drawableToBitmap(Drawable drawable)
{
    if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable)
    {
        return ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
    }

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    drawable.draw(canvas);

    return bitmap;
}

public static Bitmap getScaledBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int newWidth, int newHeight)
{
    int width = bitmap.getWidth();
    int height = bitmap.getHeight();
    float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
    float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;

    // CREATE A MATRIX FOR THE MANIPULATION
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    // RESIZE THE BIT MAP
    matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

    // RECREATE THE NEW BITMAP
    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, false);
    return resizedBitmap;
}
```

}

To call it use

```
//imgpath is the path to the image which you can save in shared preferences
   Bitmap bmp=DecodeImage.decodeFile(imgpath, 800, 1000, true);
```

Hope this helps